# Finding the top most parent

Tags: java, inheritance

My code is as follows:

```
class GlobalInfo {
     // multiple properties here
}

class RegionalInfo extends GlobalInfo {
    // multiple properties here
    GlobalInfo parent;
}

class BankInfo extends GlobalInfo {
    // multiple properties here
    GlobalInfo parent;
}
```

There could be multiple BankInfo in one RegionalInfo. And there could be multiple RegionalInfo parents inside a BankInfo object.

For e.g.,

```
BankInfo == Bank Of America

RegionalInfo == Dallas // 1st parent

RegionalInfo == Texas // Dallas's parent

RegionalInfo == MidWest // Texas's parent and final parent.
```

Per above example, the immediate parent of BankInfo object points to Dallas, and it's parent points to Texas and then it's parent point to MidWest.

In some cases, there maybe only one or two parents

For e.g.,

```
BankInfo == University Credit Union

RegionalInfo == Houston
```

So what i want to find is the, root parent of each BankInfo object. From 1st example, that will be MidWest and in 2nd it will be Houston.

I am more of a C++ developer and could come up with a code having multiple loops to find the root parents. But am hoping that in Java there might be better ways.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `parent` to `GlobalInfo`:

```
class GlobalInfo {
    GlobalInfo parent;
    // multiple properties here
}
```

Then you can do a `while` loop:

```
public GlobalInfo getRootParent(){
    if(this.parent == null){
        return null;
    }

    GlobalInfo result = this;
    while(result.parent != null){
        result = result.parent;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive loop if you move the parent attribute up into GlobalInfo.

```
public GlobalInfo getTopParent() {
   GlobalInfo result = this;
   if (this.parent != null) {
      result = this.parent.getTopParent();
   }
   return result;
}
```

As long as you have a parent, you keep going up the tree.

Comment: Caveat this will return "Midwest" for Midwest as there is no parent for it